# I Need Source Specific Multicast Implementation Clarification

Tags: networking, multicast

I read document:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3569.txt

I also had a look at

http://wiki.treck.com/IGMPv3

I am confused regarding SSM Vs SFM Vs ASM API to use!

It is my understanding that the IGMPv3 Include Mode should apply only to the SSM IP address range (232/8). Not the ASM IP range. It is also my understanding that the Exclude Mode should apply only to the ASM IP address range. Not the SSM IP range. Yet as RFC 3569 say : "Note that IGMPv3/MLDv2 does not limit (S,G) joins to only the 232/8 range. However, SSM service, as defined in [RFC 4607], is available only in this address range for IPv4." (As a side note I believe it is possible to setup some Routers such that SSM apply to the full multicast range)

Yet according to RFC 3569 SFM seems to apply to the whole ASM IP range and would use both Include mode and Exclude mode API which seems to contradict my previous assumption.

Thus my question is with which Multicast IP address range can I use the Include and Exclude mode API if my networking supports IGMPv3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs allow you to use any addresses, similarly routers can be configured to use any addresses for SSM and ASM.  However the RFC details the recommended steps for if you want to route over the Internet, i.e. through third parties using a standard common configuration.

Then you question doesn't have enough context, it is the IP stack that cares about IGMP/MLD you don't need to.  The only area of concern is not even the developer it should be the administrators selecting addresses for deployment.

Comment: RFC 3678 helped also:
Citing:

Version 3 of the Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMPv3) [3] and
version 2 of the Multicast Listener Discovery (MLDv2) protocol [4] provide the ability to communicate source filter information to the
router and hence avoid pulling down data from unwanted sources onto
the local link.  However, source filters may be implemented by the
operating system regardless of whether the routers support IGMPv3 or
MLDv2, so when the source-filter API is available, applications can
always benefit from using it.